# Страница вызывается несколько раз

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

При использовании кода

```
$(".scr").click(function () {
    $('.move').animate({left:"-100%"},400 function () {
    $("#bigblock").load("/pic.html" , function() {
            $.getScript("js/script.js")
        });          
    });
```

});

pic.html и script.js вызываются 3 раза

[вот скриншот](http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/4/3/9/1png_8936716_11030439.png)

А если добавить, например, ещё одно условие, то всё нормально, вот так

```
$(".scr").click(function () {
    $('.move').animate({left:"-100%"},400)
    $('#footer').animate({left:"-=10%"},800, function () {
    $("#bigblock").load("/pic.html" , function() {
            $.getScript("js/script.js")
        });          
    });
```

});

[скриншот](http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/5/1/0/2png_5770409_11030510.png)

Но мне не нужно это условие.

В чём может быть дело и как решить проблему?

Comment: Увас пропущены запятая и точка с запятой в первом скрипте, если написать так   
 
    $(".scr").click(function () {
    $('.move').animate({left:"-100%"}, 400, function () {
    $("#bigblock").load("/pic.html" , function() {
            $.getScript("js/script.js");
        });          
    });
});
он не будет работать правильно?

Comment: к сожалению нет, ничего не изменилось

Comment: `$('.move').length` чему равно? угадываю с первого раза. оно равно 3.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, можно поподробней. К моему стыду и сожалению, мои знания в этой области стремятся к нулю.

Comment: у меня на странице 3 элемента с классом move
если я оставляю только один элемент, то всё работает нормально.
то есть количество раз, которое вызывается страница pic.html
зависит от количества элементов с классом move.

Как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самое простое завести переменную

```
var loading = false;
$(".scr").click(function () {
  $('.move').animate({left:"-100%"}, 400, function () {
    if(!loading){
      loading = true;
      $("#bigblock").load("/pic.html" , function() {
        $.getScript("js/script.js");
      });          
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за помощь.